# Program that add all equal numbers but consecutive in an array

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and a newbie at that. Can some one help me on this problem:
to add all the numbers that equal in value and position consecutively in an array. Example
I have an array = [1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 6], and i would like it to return array = 
[1, 6, 5, 2, 6] using Ruby language. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and the linked pages. Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. We want to see evidence of your effort. Did you search for solutions? Where? Why didn't the results help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, what is the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking about? Without those it looks like you want us to write a solution for you, which is off-topic. If this is homework read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)"

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've been working on it for a while but  only be able to added two numbers instead of three or more consecutive numbers. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 6].chunk_while(&:equal?).flat_map(&:sum)
=> [1, 6, 5, 2, 6]
```

`chunk_while` permits you to group consecutive elements based on a condition. After that, you have n groups(n arrays, maybe some of them of just one element). Now you want to `map` every single array in something different (the sum of its elements). Last detail: `flat_map`, not `map`, because we want an array, not an array of arrays.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing

Comment: Also consider explaining why code works instead of just tossing it out. Remember, SO is a reference book so we need to help others to learn. [Teach, don't merely answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291533/128421)

Comment: I updated my answer. Tried, at least. My english is probably not good enough to teach, unfortunately.

Comment: Nicely done. We can fix the wording. `flat_map(&:sum)` would be more concise. `chunk_while(&:equal?).flat_map(&:sum)` would be even better.